# Django HTML Page Table Sorting

Tags: python, html, django

The following table shows quotes the customer received. But it is currently showing the oldest quote on the top and not the most recent.
Any way I can get this table to have the most recent row on the top?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Status</th>
</tr>
</thead>
{% for quote in quotes %}
<tr>
<td> <a href="/quote/{{ customer.id }}/{{ quote.id }}/">{{ quote.quote_id     }}</a></td>
<td>{{ quote.main_price }}</td>
<td>{{ quote.date_generated.date }}</td>
<td>{{ quote.status }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: What does your query look like?

Comment: where would i find that? Had someone build the django app for me. Her reply was its not possible because its a table. Just don't think she wants to do it

Comment: The query is usually stored in the `views.py`. Search for a function that includes that template's name (eg. search for `customer_quotes.html`), then edit your question and post the source code for that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this with in django use [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) on your queryset.

`order_by(*fields)`

By default, results returned by a QuerySet are ordered by the ordering tuple given by the ordering option in the model’s Meta. You can override this on a per-QuerySet basis by using the order_by method.

Example:
`Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005).order_by('-pub_date', 'headline')`

if what you are looking for is the ability to sort the HTML on the clientside you will need to use something like [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with in django use order_by on your queryset.
order_by(*fields), if you want last updated data in first means you can use

`Example.objects.order_by('-id')` , based on the fields it will work , you can user updated_time etc,

Answer (score 0):

while you can order the queryset by their `id`s, you may also make a time stamp and use it. i.e., the model with have additional field of time stamp

## models.py

```
class Quote(models.Model):
    # SOME FIELDS ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

the `created` field saves the time when the `Quote` instance is created and the `modified` field when the instance is firstly created or modified thereafter.

then the queryset is sorted by one of these fields; or using both.

```
qryset = Quote.objects.filter(SOME FILTERING).order_by('-created')
```